# Alert return data in jQuery - ajax

Tags: jquery

I have a php file, `process.php` which return a number pattern depending on the input string, from `$_POST["name"]`. I want to alert the return number using jQuery.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
$.post('/process.php', { input: 'your input' }, function(data) {
    alert(data);
}, 'text');
```

Comment: its using POST method ... not working.. can u post a full code??

Comment: You can use $.get() or $.post() what ever process.php accepts